# Angular2 ControlGroup valueChanges on initial bind

Tags: forms, typescript, angular, observable

I have a form with some `<input type="text">` widgets and I have noticed that `ControlGroup.valueChanges` is being called upon initial databind when using `[ngFormModel]` and `ngControl`.

This means that the user thinks that the form has been changed upon initial load.

Is this normal or should I be using a different observable to track changes made the by the user?

I am using Angular2 RC3 and the following version import for forms:

```
import {ControlGroup, Validators, FormBuilder} from '@angular/common';
```

Comment: can you please post your package.json

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think that's just how it works, however if you just want to track if changes are made by user, you should employ `ControlGroup.dirty` or `formControl.dirty` with the `changes` Observable.

```
ControlGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {

 if(ControlGroup.dirty){
   console.log('This change is made by User.');
 } 
 else {
   console.log('This change is Automated. before any User interaction.');
 }

})
```